# javascript validation not happening

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have written the following form in my html file.

```
 <form name = "myForm" method="post" action="" id="comment_form" class="comment_form" onsubmit="return validateForm()"  >{% csrf_token %}
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*">
                    </div>
                    <div class="span6">
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name*">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span8">
                        <textarea name="message" id="txt_message" placeholder="Message*" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4">
                        <button class="btn " type="button"><i class="li_paperplane"></i>Send message</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

And I have added this javascript function inside my HTML file

```
<script>function validateForm()
     {
    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
    var y=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var a=document.forms["myForm"]["message"].value;
    var atpos=y.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=y.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (x==null || x=="" ||y==null||y==""||a==""||a==null)
    {
        alert("All fields must be filled out");
        return false;}
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=y.length)
    {
        alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }

    else{
        alert("Thank you for your response");
        return true;
    }
}</script>
```

On click of Send Message button I am not getting any response from the javascript. The code looks fine and the same code is working on another HTML file. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "Send Message" button is just a button -- it doesn't submit the form. You can either use an `<input type="submit">` or use JavaScript on your `<button>` to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an onclick event to your button. Add the following attribute to the button

**Syntax:**

```
onclick="document.NameOfTheForm.submit();"
```

So in this syntax you have to add following

```
onclick="document.myForm.submit();"
```